# Swift Combine correct use of Future

Tags: swift, future, combine

Say I have a three layered architecture (Data, Domain and View) and I want to access and provide some data. The three layers are part of different targets and are initialised using dependency injection.

In the domain layer I have the following types:

```swift
protocol BookListRepository: AnyObject {
    func getAll() -> Future<[Book], Error>
}
```

```swift
final class BookService {
    private let repository: BookListRepository

    init(repository: BookListRepository) {
        self.repository = repository
    }

    func getAll() -> Future<[Book], Error> {
        repository.getAll()
    }
}
```

In data I define the following:

```swift
class BookApi: BookListRepository {
    func getAll() -> Future<[Book], Error> {
        .init { promise in
            let cancellable = urlSession
                .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
                .tryMap() { element -> Data in
                    guard 
                        let httpResponse = element.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                        httpResponse.statusCode == 200 
                    else { throw URLError(.badServerResponse) }
                    return element.data
                }
                .decode(type: [Book]].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                    guard case let .failure(error) = completion
                    promise(.failure(error))
                 },
                receiveValue: { books in 
                    promise(.success(books))
                }
    }
}
```

In my view layer I would access this in a similar way to this:

```swift
let service: BookService = .init(repository: BookApi())
service
    .getAll()
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) }) { books in
        // Displau
    }
    .store(in: &cancelables)
```

My question here is the following: Is this in any way a good practice and if not what is the correct/preferred way to achieve what I want.

Comment: Why are you converting a `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` into a `Future`? Why do you think you should be using a `Future` in the first place? Your Combine interfaces should most of the time not expose the actual underlying `Publisher`, so your return types should be `AnyPublisher`.

Comment: “Is this in any way a good practice” No, probably not. Wrapping a data task publisher in a future makes little sense (a data task publisher is itself a future), and wrapping an entire pipeline, right down to the sink and store, inside another publisher is nutty. The whole purpose and spirit of Combine seems violated here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, I'm new to combine and need to get in the spirit of it.

Answer (score 0):

In Combine (and other similar frameworks), subscribers care about what values and what errors publishers emit, so it's customary to use a `AnyPublisher` at an API boundary.

```
protocol BookListRepository: AnyObject {
    func getAll() -> AnyPublisher<[Book], Error>
}
```

Operators `.sink` and `.assign` create a subscription to the publisher. You'd want to subscribe only at the final consumption site of the data, and return the publisher in the intermediate steps:

```
final class BookService {
    private let repository: BookListRepository

    func getAll() -> AnyPublisher<[Book], Error> {
        repository.getAll()
    }
}

class BookApi: BookListRepository {
    func getAll() -> AnyPublisher<[Book], Error> {
        urlSession
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .tryMap() { element -> Data in
                 guard 
                     let httpResponse = element.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                     httpResponse.statusCode == 200 
                 else { throw URLError(.badServerResponse) }

                 return element.data
            }
            .decode(type: [Book].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```